# How do I trigger picture in picture on Safari 10

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-video, safari10

Safari 10 introduces picture in picture. The button is there for html5 video standard controls, but how do I trigger it by javascript?

[Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH11-DontLinkElementID_13):

> If you use custom HTML5 video controls, you can add Picture in Picture functionality using the JavaScript presentation mode API.

With no further references.

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/q/39430331/4691734

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use Javascript to activate the picture-in-picture mode. It will run by this way.

```
document.querySelector("video").webkitSetPresentationMode("picture-in-picture")
```

Comment: Next question. How do I trigger in on Netflix? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH9-SW18

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a Netflix account, so I cannot try it

Comment: Works fine with Netflix, just run this in js console when watching something.

Answer (score 0):

***This question already have been asked***

Anyways see this

Here is Safari's [API](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_0.html)

And I also have a [How to PiP video in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39430331/4691734)

Check support

```
webkitSupportsPresentationMode
```

Set Mode

```
webkitSetPresentationMode
```