# Full height video in safari/firefox

Tags: html, css

does anybody know why the video html tag isn't covering 100% height in safari and firefox ? It works in chrome and edge. I need the video to cover 100% height of it's parent element, hope someone can help.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
}

.video_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 1440px;
  background-color: rgba(32, 32, 177, 0.55);
  text-align: center;
}

.video {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <video class="video" muted="" loop="" autoplay="" playsinline style="">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>

  <div class="video_content">
    <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dumm</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The video has its height set to `auto`: how will that ever cover 100% of the container height?

Comment: Setting it to 100% height doesn't work either...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safari html5 video fullscreen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27452624/safari-html5-video-fullscreen-size)

Comment: Since you accepted an answer, I'll follow up with why `100%` height doesn't work. The parent element needs a height set for that to work, otherwise there is no reference to what 100% should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your .video with following :

```css
.video {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, that did it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
}

.video_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 1440px;
  background-color: rgba(32, 32, 177, 0.55);
  text-align: center;
}

.video {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <video class="video" muted="" loop="" autoplay="" playsinline style="">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>

  <div class="video_content">
    <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dumm</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue today, and found that, in my specific use case (which was an absolutely-positioned video that should display 100vw and 100vh), it was Safari user agent's default `object-fit: contain` on the `<video>` element that cause the video to not display full height. Adding `object-fit: cover` corrected it in this situation.